# Double-reduce a sequence of integers

Tags: code-golf, sequence

Consider a function \$r\$ where

$$
r(i,k)= \begin{cases}
L_{i+1}-L_i, & \text{if}\ k =0\ \text{  (1st reduction)} \\
r(i,0)-r(\lfloor \log_2{k} \rfloor,k-2^{\lfloor \log_2{k} \rfloor}) & \text{if}\ k \geq 1\ \text{  (2nd reduction)}
\end{cases}
$$

where \$k<2^i\$ and \$L\$ is a finite sequence of integers.

For example, assuming that \$L = \{0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5\}\$,

for \$i=0\$,

- \$r(0,0) = L_1-L_0 = 1-0 = 1\$.

for \$i=1\$,

- \$r(1,0) = L_2-L_1 = 1-1 = 0\$.
- \$r(1,1) = r(1,0)-r(0,0) = 0-1 = -1\$.

for \$i=2\$,

- \$r(2,0) = L_3-L_2 = 2-1 = 1\$.
- \$r(2,1) = r(2,0)-r(0,0) = 1-1 = 0\$.
- \$r(2,2) = r(2,0)-r(1,0) = 1-0 = 1\$.
- \$r(2,3) = r(2,0)-r(1,1) = 1+1 = 2\$.

The **double-reduction of \$L\$** is created by concatenating results from \$i=0\$, \$i=1\$, ..., until every consecutive pair of elements of \$L\$ are visited.

In layperson's terms, this function subtracts two consecutive terms of \$L\$, and then subtract every previous-calculated subtraction from that result. Note that every call of \$r(i,k)\$, for \$i>0\$ and \$k>0\$, is already computed.

### Input

A list of integers `L`. You can assume its size will be always greater or equal to 3.

### Output

A [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) representing the double-reduction of `L`.

> - **Indexing:** Both \$0\$- and \$1\$-based indexing are allowed, and the following rules can be applied with both these types of indexing.
> - **Format:** The answers can use one of the following output methods:
>
>   - Given some index \$n\$, it can return the \$n\$-th entry of the list.
>   - Given some index \$n\$, it can return all entries up to the \$n\$-th one in the sequence.
>   - Without taking any index, it can output *all* entries by printing them one by one or by returning a list.

#### Test cases

Here's the test cases for positive numbers, even numbers, prime numbers, Fibonacci numbers, power-of-2 numbers, lucky numbers and signed Fibonacci numbers, respectively:

```
[1, 2, 3] -> [1, 1, 0]
[2, 4, 6, 8] -> [2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11] -> [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5] -> [1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, -1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32] -> [1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 8, 7, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 5, 16, 15, 14, 15, 12, 13, 14, 13, 8, 9, 10, 9, 12, 11, 10, 11]
[1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 15, 21] -> [2, 4, 2, 2, 0, -2, 0, 4, 2, 0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 0, -2, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, -2, 0, 2, 0, 0, -2, -4, -2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 4, 6, 8, 6, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4, 2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 6, 6, 4, 2, 4, 8, 6, 4, 6, 6, 8, 10, 8]
[0, 1, -1, 2, -3, 5, -8] -> [1, -2, -3, 3, 2, 5, 6, -5, -6, -3, -2, -8, -7, -10, -11, 8, 7, 10, 11, 5, 6, 3, 2, 13, 14, 11, 10, 16, 15, 18, 19, -13, -14, -11, -10, -16, -15, -18, -19, -8, -7, -10, -11, -5, -6, -3, -2, -21, -20, -23, -24, -18, -19, -16, -15, -26, -27, -24, -23, -29, -28, -31, -32]
```

Your solution should be implemented with fewest bytes as possible.

<sub>Brownie points for beating or matching my 70-bytes Python answer.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
⊞υ⁰ＦＥΦθκ⁻ι§θκ≔⁺υ⁻ιυυＩΦυκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gtDhDo1RHwUDTmistv0hBwzexQMMtM6cktUijUEchW1NHwTczr7RYI1NHwbHEMy8ltQIiDgQKjsXFmel5GgE5QPlSJIWlmpogwporoCgzr0TDObG4BGZmKUSv9f//0dFGOgrGOgqmOgrmOgqGhrGx/3XLcgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Adapted from both @Arnauld's and @loopywalt's answers.

```
⊞υ⁰
```

Start with a list of just `0`.

```
ＦＥΦθκ⁻ι§θκ
```

Loop over the list of differences of the input array.

```
≔⁺υ⁻ιυυ
```

Subtract all of the elements of the output array from the current difference and then concatenate the result onto the output array.

```
ＩΦυκ
```

Output all but the first element of the output array.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 63 bytes

```python
f=lambda l,*L,a=[]:L and f(*L,a=a+[L[0]-l-b for b in[0]+a])or a
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVNLTsMwEF2w6ymsrhKwUeyYNEUKrNjlBlEWrkpFpDSJoCCx5hhsuoE7wWmYT2zMJ4rGnpk3b37J6_v0fLgbh-Px7fGwU-XH9a7q3X6zdaKXp7V0VdNe1sINW7FLSHdnTd1krerVRuzGe7ER3QD6mWtT0NxMc4OuGlxinG6HJEsvFwKeTo7V3k3J7ZPrZX3-MPXdIVmqq2Wakn-674ZDApm6tKrGlMmOnycvjZbCSJG3Ql0JVODN2kUDNitFIUXJHkOwzEu8MCqX4kKKFQTqwGGIhmVG0hLQRBItwMBu7a0XgQMcSkcM5uc986qK8-X_QbWv27e6mGuEEkqwQpO5-VV7XG9J7RUkLXVbkMRAjaedTwzNZ53j1nDL-ECnZhUmRSXkRLmeo4DB6DBsS9m5UcWHjVYQ1mN_gTLvM8EUHKgry2cItWHRJGPiOGGMiWNLrxYegB2WYbPzehR_JqoMc1azlcfMQ1UIKdhOfqBTKyShRWu_Cx6ij2KGMHk_ZL8dLGmN4UiKCCKaKTEZohTCFOH-5PxTlaHyaaBksj_ivzkN3szKQxiMEIPgHFngw1vwz_gF)

Takes splatted input. Returns the entire double-reduction.

### How?

Once one all but ignores the confusing double indexing there is an obvious rather simple recursion.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 61 bytes

An implementation of what the function *really* does, as described in the *layman's terms* paragraph of the challenge.

```javascript
a=>a.map(v=>a=[0,...b].map(k=>1/a&&b.push(v-a-k))&&v,b=[])&&b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3LDoIwEEX3fMXEBWmTabXgA2PKzq8gXQwo4osSUX4fR2pMTLo490zu7YUG6qvHuXuq1h@OY21HsjnpO3ViYLDFArXWpZvM1eZmTnFc6u7VN2JQpK5SxvGApS0cQznuigigMAgJQurwE5iWCGuE7JdThBXCBsGY4BaM0/segw2ZyxnfeCBNfj6d6lv2TIbHkr8lFaoqfKQyF7lI1/6xp6oRBDaHyre9vx31zZ9ELUjqiz@3YoYwk1KObw)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>              // a[] = input
a.map(v =>        // for each value v in a[]:
  a =             //   update a:
    [0, ...b]     //     for 0 and each value in b[]
    .map(k =>     //     loaded in k:
      1 / a       //       do nothing if this is the 1st iteration,
      &&          //       i.e. a is still the input array (*)
      b.push(     //       otherwise, push in b[]:
        v - a - k //         the current value, minus the previous one,
      )           //         minus k
    )             //     end of inner map()
    && v,         //     save v in a
  b = []          //   start with b[] = empty array
)                 // end of outer map()
&& b              // return b[]
```

*<sub>(*) The input is guaranteed to contain at least 3 integers, as per the challenge rules. So it can't be coerced to a number.</sub>*

---

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 92 bytes

This was an attempt at implementing the definition literally.

```javascript
L=>{for(n=1;L[-~(g=Math.log2)(n)];)print((r=k=>~(k-=2**(i=~~g(k)))&&L[i+1]-L[i]-r(k))(n++))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9Bi8IwEIXv/RVzkhmbiEldt0uZ3rx1f0HJIQit3UqVWLyI/et1NIsgBPLeN7w3zJ@/@ss@dOdRX/O54bni8tacAg5siqrWE7b868fD6nhqLeFArqBz6IYRMXDP5YS9ZrtcYsfT1GJPRItFVXepcVo@p8OT4ZCmRPe5qBOA2iiwCjKnnkbURsFWQf72mYIvBd8KjIlsLfL1/oeRRi/hXGZSkNk3z17xH@GijJTZjyYdozou0rlLXLKSo3d@f0APXMINGvRUQDxVxJ3mBw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://haskell.org), 48 bytes

```haskell
r a[_]=a
r a(x:y:l)=r(a++[y-x-z|z<-0:a])$y:l
r[]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Î¥vDyα‚˜}¦
```

Inspired by [*@Neil*'s Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269758/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9vc2FiaWX//8OOwqV2RHnOseKAmsucfcKm//9bMiwzLDUsNywxMV0) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/g@JDS8tcKs9tfNQw6/Sc2kPL/uv8j4421DHSMY7ViTbSMdEx07EAs4x1THXMdQwNgRwDHUMdsBIdUyAPxDLRsdAxNNMxNgLzjYEKLXUMjXUMTXWMYBp0Qep0QaboWsTGAgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Î         # Push 0 and the input-list
 ¥        # Get the deltas/forward-differences of the input-list
  v       # Loop over each of its integers `y`:
   D      #  Duplicate the current list,
          #  which is the 0 in the first iteration
    yα    #  Get the absolute difference of each value with integer `y`
      ‚   #  Pair this list together with the duplicated list (or the 0)
       ˜  #  Flatten it to a single list
  }¦      # After the loop: remove the leading 0
          # (after which the list is output implicitly as result)
```